# "New comments posted" notification when writing answers?

Tags: feature-request, comment, notifications

It has happened to me a couple of times that I've posted an answer only to find that someone has written something similar in a comment meanwhile. I think it would be nice to get a "new comments have been posted" notification while writing answers, just like the already existing "new answers have been posted". (In particular I would like this for comments on the question itself; maybe not so much for comments on other answers.)

Comment: We don't control such things; if you want to make this request, ask it on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Qiaochu: OK. I was under the impression that the some of the developers read questions here as well, but maybe that assumption was too optimistic.

Comment: @Hans: whether that's true or not, it's still not the appropriate place to make such a request because (as far as I know) these changes aren't made specific to one SE site but are made across the entire network.

Comment: @Qiaochu: it's actually preferable if users post these things on their own metas first - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on While implementing this would probably require a change to the underlying engine, the *rationale* for the change might make more sense in the context of a particular site... It pays to discuss it in context first, and take it to MSO if/when you want to expose it to users of other sites. FWIW, we (the SE team) do monitor these meta posts, so you won't be completely ignored even if no one else from your site is interested.

Comment: @Hans: how would you see this being useful? Can you give an example of a comment that would alter how you would answer the question?

Comment: @Shog9: Well, to take the case that prompted this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41019/1242, where I gave a not very deep answer, consisting mainly of a link to a webpage. If I had seen that the same link was posted in a comment just after I started writing my answer, I don't think I would have bothered finishing it.

Comment: Several years later, we can see that new comments have posted without reloading the page.